# Centering nth element when using grids at the beginning of a row in css

Tags: css, css-grid

```
  margin: 20px 20px 90px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  justify-items: center;
```

When using grid, how do you make sure that the fourth item is in the center instead of the left side?

Example:

I want this:

```
[ ] [ ] [ ]

    [ ]
```

instead of:

```
[ ] [ ] [ ]

[ ]
```

[ ] represents a div element like a Card.

Comment: could you add the html as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make with set [`grid-column: span 3;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column) for 4th child.

```css
.container {
  margin: 50px 40px 100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 40px;
  justify-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container div {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.container div:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would you do this with styled elements?

Comment: @pomegrenade if you share  your code (complete html and css) I can help you.